# Text is not fully shown in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextfield

They say a single image is worth 1000 words:

[image]

I'll just note that the size is set to default. (build in NetBeans)
any idea how do I fix this?

Adam.

Comment: It's embedded inside a JScrollPane?

Comment: Do u change font after frame is created?

Comment: no font changing no thing is going on, As it seem... if there was anything I would mention it

Comment: I revalidate the container of the text field

Comment: The picture is nice, but code would be good as well :) What kind of layout are you using? What LAF? What OS? You say the size is set to default - the size of the textfields? Are the textfields contents populated initially, or are they set later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the LNF that was assigned to the frame, once I've changed that, it all works fine.

Comment: LNF? Can you elaborate this please?

Answer (score 3):

Without you showing code, I'd say that your JTextField width is not set to be wide enough. You can resize it to be large enough for the number of characters you anticipate.

However, this does not guarantee that the user will not type in more characters, which would show the text cutoff as well.

You can extend the `Document` that JTextField uses to add the maximum character restriction, as shown at
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0198.html

Comment: I know I can resize it manually, the point is to fit the text field width to the characters it holds, so default seemed like the right way for me. bottom line is that the default size is two pixels short. and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

what are the lengths of your data,it seems you changed the layout and that's causing that problem as the border seems also occupying half of the character.

Comment: I thought that could be the case, any idea how to remove the border?

Answer (score 0):

> They say a single image is worth 1000
>   words:

Actually its not. When posting a question a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is worth 1000 words.

Stuff like that usually happens when you don't use a layout manager. Assuming (which is all we can do since you didn't post any code) that you are using a proper layout manager then your basic code for creating a text field to display 3 characters is:

```
JTextField width = new JTextField(3);
```